# Customizing salesforce UI

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, ui

My company is moving to salesforce and most of the time the requirements I get are something like

1. Give me a single page where I can do 10 things
2. The data is too cryptic for the end user to understand so cover up the raw data and present it in a way that they can understand
3. Wanting to edit inline and add inline etc...
4. One place for everyone to do everything

What I am looking for is , can someone guide or explain what I should be doing and what I should not be doing?

Somethings I see  as issues with heavy customization are 
1. Handling permissions based on the user - I would rather salesforce handle permissions etc by using page layouts etc.. 
2. Having one place for all users is a maintenance issue

Also is there a blog/site I can use to read about some UI guidelines

Comment: If you need to build a custom page layout I would recommend using lightning-record-form or lightning-record-edit-form as both handle permissions automatically without additional code.  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-form/documentation

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation

Comment: Working/customizing within Salesforce is also about having good soft-skills to discuss the issues between business needs and technical options. Trying to undo the Salesforce UI is pretty drastic. I think the better option is to learn how to maximize what Salesforce gives you so you can present its strengths rather than only focusing on the weaknesses.